# Refresh Token OAuth Authentication Angular 4+

Tags: angular, http, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I was working with the `Http` clase from Angular but I decide to make the migration and work with the new `HttpClient`, and I was trying to create a solution with `Interceptors` to manage the cases when I need to refresh the token and when I need to modify the header to put the Authorization Token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I found these post and so many others :

- https://medium.com/@amcdnl/the-new-http-client-in-angular-4-3-754bd3ff83a8
- https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

... but those solutions are perfect if you just want to handle the action to put the Authorization Header. Then I come up with this solution

```
@Injectable()
export class RefreshTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private injector: Injector, private authService: Auth) {
  }


  private getRequestWithAuthentication(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler, auth: OAuthService): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const  req = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', auth.getHeaderAuthorization())
      });
    return next.handle(req);
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // To avoid cyclic dependency
    const auth = this.injector.get(OAuthService);

    if (auth.hasAuthorization()) {
      return this.getRequestWithAuthentication(request, next, auth);
    } else if (auth.hasAuthorizationRefresh() && request.url !== AUTHORIZE_URL) {
      return auth.refreshToken().flatMap(
        (res: any) => {
          auth.saveTokens(res);
          return this.getRequestWithAuthentication(request, next, auth);
        }
      ).catch(() => {
        return next.handle(request);
      });
    } else if (request.url === AUTHORIZE_URL) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    return this.getRequestWithAuthentication(request, next, auth);
  }
}
```

The main idea with this is  simple:

- First, I'm injecting a service where I have all the logic to determinate if  I have the **token** or the **refresh token** and of course the action to save it and get it.
- If I have the authorization (which is the **token** to put in the header) I am just return the request with the Authorization Header, if not I am check if I have the **refresh token** and I am trying to get it from the server and then I'm waitng until I have the token to pass the request.
- The constant **AUTHORIZE_URL** it's a string with the route from the server that I am using to get the token or refresh it. The reason because I'm checking this is because I am making a request with `HttpClient` in the `OAuthService` so It's  gonna pass from the interceptor too and It's gonna make a infinite loop if I don't check it.

> This Solution work fine in some cases, but the thing is when for example the **token expired** and you have multiple request, every request is going to try to refresh the token.

---

After this I found this solution but I wanna know what do you think about code and way that I'm doing it.

Ok, First I created a Service to save the state of the **refresh token request** and Observable to know when the request is done.

#### This is my Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class RefreshTokenService {
  public processing: boolean = false;
  public storage: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  public publish(value: any) {
    this.storage.next(value);
  }
}
```

> I noticed that It was better if I have two Interceptors one to refresh the token and handle that and one to put the Authorization Header if exist.

#### This the Interceptor for Refresh the Token:

```
@Injectable()
  export class RefreshTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private injector: Injector, private tokenService: RefreshTokenService) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      const auth = this.injector.get(OAuthService);
      if (!auth.hasAuthorization() && auth.hasAuthorizationRefresh() && !this.tokenService.processing && request.url !== AUTHORIZE_URL) {
        this.tokenService.processing = true;
        return auth.refreshToken().flatMap(
          (res: any) => {
            auth.saveTokens(res);
            this.tokenService.publish(res);
            this.tokenService.processing = false;
            return next.handle(request);
          }
        ).catch(() => {
          this.tokenService.publish({});
          this.tokenService.processing = false;
          return next.handle(request);
        });
      } else if (request.url === AUTHORIZE_URL) {
        return next.handle(request);
      }

      if (this.tokenService.processing) {
        return this.tokenService.storage.flatMap(
          () => {
            return next.handle(request);
          }
        );
      } else {
        return next.handle(request);
      }
    }
  }
```

So here I'm waiting to the refresh token to be available or fails and then I release the request that needs the Authorization Header.

#### This is the Interceptor to put the Authorization Header:

```
@Injectable()
  export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      const auth = this.injector.get(OAuthService);
      let req = request;
      if (auth.hasAuthorization()) {
        req = request.clone({
          headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', auth.getHeaderAuthorization())
        });
      }

      return next.handle(req).do(
        () => {},
        (error: any) => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (error.status === 401) {
              auth.logOut();
            }
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

#### And my main module is something like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    OAuthService,
    AuthService,
    RefreshTokenService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: RefreshTokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Please any feedback will be welcome and if I'm doning something wrong tell me. I'm testing with **Angular 4.4.6** but I don't know if it work on angular 5, I think should work.

Comment: You say you find it better to have two interceptors, one for each token. Can you tell us what makes this better for you ? Thanks for your interesting source code by the way.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking for a solution to this in Angular 4 (maybe slight changes needed for Angular 5+), I came up with the following solution:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    private _refreshRequest: Observable<ApiResult<any>> | null = null;

    constructor(
        private _router: Router, 
        private _tokenStorage: TokenStorageService,
        private _injector: Injector) {
    }

    private _addTokenHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
        const authToken = this._tokenStorage.authToken;

        if (!authToken) {
            return request;
        }

        return request.clone({setHeaders: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken.value}});
    }

    private _fail() {
        this._tokenStorage.clearTokens();
        this._router.navigate(['/login']);
        return throwError(new HttpErrorResponse({status: 401}));
    }

    private _refreshAuthToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        // AuthService has the following dependency chain:
        // ApiService -> HttpClient -> HTTP_INTERCEPTORS
        // If injected at the constructor this causes a circular dependency error. 
        const authService = <AuthService>this._injector.get(AuthService);

        if (this._refreshRequest === null) {
            // Send the auth token refresh request
            this._refreshRequest = authService.refreshAuthToken();
            this._refreshRequest.subscribe(() => this._refreshRequest = null);
        }

        // Wait for the auth token refresh request to finish before sending the pending request
        return this._refreshRequest
            .flatMap(result => {
                if (result.success) {
                    // Auth token was refreshed, continue with pending request
                    return this._sendRequest(this._addTokenHeader(request), next);
                }

                // Refreshing the auth token failed, fail the pending request
                return this._fail();
            });
    }

    private _sendRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        return next.handle(request).catch((err: HttpErrorResponse, caught) => {
            // Send the user to the login page If there are any 'Unauthorized' responses
            if (err.status === 401) {
                this._router.navigate(['/login']);
            }

            return Observable.throw(err);
        });
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (request.url.indexOf('/api/auth') !== -1) {
            // This interceptor should not be applied to auth requests
            return this._sendRequest(request, next);
        }

        const authToken = this._tokenStorage.authToken;
        const refreshToken = this._tokenStorage.refreshToken;

        // Attempt to refresh the auth token if it is expired or about to expire
        if (authToken && authToken.expiresWithinSeconds(60)) {
            if (refreshToken && !refreshToken.isExpired) {
                return this._refreshAuthToken(request, next);
            }
            else {
                // Auth token has expired and cannot be refreshed
                return this._fail();
            }
        }

        return this._sendRequest(this._addTokenHeader(request), next);
    }
}
```

This will issue an auth token refresh request to the server if the current auth token is expired, but there is a valid refresh token. Further requests are buffered until the pending refresh request completes.

Not shown is the source to:
- `TokenStorageService` which just uses localStorage
- `Jwt` class that wraps a token and makes the token claims like expiry date easy to access
- `ApiResult` which is just a simple wrapper around `HttpResponse` for my application, and not particularly relevant to anything here

**Edit:** Angular 6/7

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { 
    HttpEvent, 
    HttpInterceptor, 
    HttpHandler, 
    HttpRequest, 
    HttpErrorResponse, 
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ApiResult } from '../../api';

import { TokenStorageService } from './token-storage.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';


@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    private _refreshRequest: Observable<ApiResult> | null = null;

    constructor(
        private _router: Router, 
        private _tokenStorage: TokenStorageService,
        @Inject('BASE_URL') private _baseUrl: string,
        private _injector: Injector) {
    }

    private _addTokenHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
        const authToken = this._tokenStorage.authToken;

        if (!authToken) {
            return request;
        }

        return request.clone({setHeaders: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken.value}});
    }

    private _forceLogin() {
        this._tokenStorage.clearTokens();

        this._router.navigate(['/account/login'], { queryParams: {
            message: 'Your session has expired. Please re-enter your credentials.'
        }});
    }

    private _fail() {
        this._forceLogin();
        return throwError(new HttpErrorResponse({status: 401}));
    }

    private _refreshAuthToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        // AuthService has the following dependency chain:
        // ApiService -> HttpClient -> HTTP_INTERCEPTORS
        // If injected at the constructor this causes a circular dependency error. 
        const authService = <AuthService>this._injector.get(AuthService);

        if (this._refreshRequest === null) {
            // Send the auth token refresh request
            this._refreshRequest = authService.refreshAuthToken();
            this._refreshRequest.subscribe(() => this._refreshRequest = null);
        }

        // Wait for the auth token refresh request to finish before sending the pending request
        return this._refreshRequest.pipe(flatMap(result => {
            if (result.success) {
                // Auth token was refreshed, continue with pending request
                return this._sendRequest(this._addTokenHeader(request), next);
            }

            // Refreshing the auth token failed, fail the pending request
            return this._fail();
        }));
    }

    private _sendRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            // Send the user to the login page If there are any 'Unauthorized' responses
            if (err.status === 401) {
                this._forceLogin();
            }

            return throwError(err);
        }));
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (request.url.indexOf(this._baseUrl) === -1  || request.url.indexOf('/api/auth') !== -1) {
            // This interceptor should not be applied to non-api requests or auth requests
            return this._sendRequest(request, next);
        }

        const authToken = this._tokenStorage.authToken;
        const refreshToken = this._tokenStorage.refreshToken;

        // Attempt to refresh the auth token if it is expired or about to expire
        if (authToken && authToken.expiresWithinSeconds(60)) {
            if (refreshToken && !refreshToken.isExpired) {
                return this._refreshAuthToken(request, next);
            }
            else {
                // Auth token has expired and cannot be refreshed
                return this._fail();
            }
        }

        return this._sendRequest(this._addTokenHeader(request), next);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , Could you you please give full code base for angular 5 including TokenStorage, we are using angualr5-adal library and things are not working for us. Thank you.